# Multiple instances of server side jQuery Datatables on one page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have two jquery Datatables that loads json values returned from the server. However only the first datable instance loads the data. Viewing the error returned from Firebug, I get "TypeError: this.domElement.parentNode is null" and Chrome also gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null " in its javascript console.

Below is my init code for the datatables

```
$(function() {
    var roleTable = $('#grid[rel*=roles_grid]').dataTable( {"bJQueryUI": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "bSortClasses": true, 
                "oTableTools": { "sSwfPath": "resources/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf" },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bRetrieve": true, 
                "sAjaxSource": "resources/server/json/setup.json.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "description" },
                    { "mDataProp": "notes" },
                    { "mDataProp": "id" }
                ]
            });

            var usersTable = $('#grid[rel*=users_grid]').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "bSortClasses": true, 
                "oTableTools": { "sSwfPath": "resources/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf" },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,  
                "sAjaxSource": "resources/server/json/users.json.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "staff_no" },
                    { "mDataProp": "lastname" },
                    { "mDataProp": "firstname" },
                    { "mDataProp": "email" },
                    { "mDataProp": "primary_phone" },
                    { "mDataProp": "secondary_phone" },
                    { "mDataProp": "description" },
                    { "mDataProp": "id" }
                ]
            });
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post the html also. :)

Comment: Found a solution, I just had to give each table a different id instead of using different rel. My Bad. thanks.